# Are different writing systems other than (extended) Latin alphabet used in Esperanto?

Tags: writing

Would using (for example) cyrillic for writing in Esperanto be considered correct?
Екземпле, чу чи тиу фразо естас коректа ен Есперанто? Се ви компренас серба цирила алфабето, ви повус капабли компрени чи тио.

I'm asking by trying to draw parallel between the fact that no *exact* pronunciation of each letter was ever given (correct me if I'm wrong), and that it's mostly based on the native language of the speaker (*r* being the best example, I think). If the native *pronunciation* is allowed to creep in, does the same hold for *writing sytem*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cyrillic has the capability for phonetic representation, though this may vary depending on the actual slavonic language.

However as Esperanto aims at being a bridge language, using a non-Latin transliterion defies its goal.

It could be used for Esperanto-names, where the context must be in the local script: "Esperanto-domo" in an urban subvention form. Or "Johano" in a passport. Far fetched, maybe for (phonetic) sample text in Esperanto for the native population.

So no, one will not ever see Esperanto texts in Cyrillic, Sioux, Katakana.
"(In-)Correctness" does not seem to fit the classification however.

There are just three transliterations of Esperanto:

- Braille (special Esperanto letters)
- Gesture language (spelling of letters)
- Stenography (like Unesteno)

And there still is the mangled latin transcription, where the Esperanto letters could be written, and are replaced.

About the prononciation: there are accents, but the individual sounds are well defined. There are slight variations, foreign influence by native language, or
by context: `e` in `sento` and `preni` (length and tone).

Answer (score 3):

There’s certainly no mention of being able to use alternative alphabets and spellings in the Fundamento or PMEG so I don’t think it could be considered correct by any official means. Except perhaps to aid beginners to understand the pronunciation I can’t think of any reason to do this. If everybody starts writing with their own native spelling system the written language would quickly become very difficult to understand for an international audience. This is different from allowing variations in pronunciation of some letters because that is only a minor hindrance to comprehension and it’s difficult to master the correct pronunciation.

> Sait mie vèrquasse coune Franntsa litèroumau, dgie nait plou aistasse commprènaiblat.

Answer (score 1):

Mi havas iom da prefero por skribanta Esperanto uzanta la Cirila alfabeto nur ĉar ĝi estas diferenta de la latina alfabeto kiu mi kutima, sed unu problemo kun skribanta Esperanto uzanta la Cirila alfabeto estas kiu litero ni uzas por iom da sonoj kiel "Һ" aŭ "Ҳ" por "H". "Ĥ" povus ankoraŭ esti "Х" kiel en Rusa. Mi mem uzas "Хь". Ĉu ni uzas "Е" aŭ "Э" por la sono "e"?  Ĉu ni uzas "Џ" aŭ "Дж" por "Ĝ"?  Mi uzas "Дж". Mi uzas "уь" (de la Ĉeĉena alfabeto) anstataŭe "ў" por "ŭ". Ĉiukaze, la Rusa klavaro ke mi uzas havas la klavo "x" asignita al "ь".  Mi pensis pri uzanta "ъ" anstataŭe "ь", sed mi pensas ke "ь" estas plej simila.  Ĉi tio problemo ne ekzistas kun la Latina alfabeto. La Latina alfabeto estis elektita anstataŭ Cirila ĉar ĝi estas pli facila lerni (kaj tajpi) por la plejparto de la mondo.

la nur razono ke ili uzis la Cirila alfabeto estis ĉar la plejparto de homoj ĉirkaŭ Pollando ne havis tajpskribiloj kun Latina literoj tiel ili uzis tajpskribiloj kun Cirila literoj.

Ми ҳавас иом да преферо пор скрибанта Есперанто узанта ла Цирила алфабето нур чар джи естас диферента де ла Латина алфабето киу ми кутима, сед уну проблемо кун скрибанта Есперанто узанта ла Цирила алфабето естас киу литеро ни узас пор иом да соной киел "Һ" аў "Ҳ" пор "H". "Ĥ" повус анкорауь ести "Х" киел ен Руса. Ми мем узас "Хь". Чу ни узас "Е' ауь "Э" пор ла соно "e"? Чу ни узас "Џ" ауь "Дж" пор "Ĝ"? Ми узас "Дж". Ми узас "уь" (де ла Чечена алфабето) анстатауье "ў" пор "ŭ". Чиуказе, ла Руса клаваро ке ми узас хьавас ла клаво "x" асигнита ал "ь". Ми пенсас при узанта "ъ" анстатауье "ь', сед ми пенсас ке "ь" естас плей симила. Чи тио проблемо не екзистас кун ла Латина алфабето . Ла Латина алфабето естис електита анстатауь Цирила чар джи естас пли фацила лерни (кай тайпи) пор ла плейпарто де ла мондо.

Ла нур разоно ке или узис ла Цирила алфабето естис чар ла плейпарто де хьомой чиркауь Полландо не хьавис тайпскрибилой кун Латина литерой тиел или узис тайпскрибилой кун Цирила литерой.

Comment: Ĉi tie estas la oficiala Cirila alfabeto por Esperanto kiu estis uzita ĉirkaŭ Pollando dum la 1800aj nur ĉar ili ne havis tajpiloj kun latinaj literoj. (Чи тие естас ла официала Цирила алфабето пор Есперанто киу естис узита чиркаў Полландо дум ла 1800ај нур чар или не һавис тајпилој кун латинај литерој) https://www.omniglot.com/conscripts/esperantocyrillic.htm